# sql like/where exists error with insert statement

Tags: sql

I want to :

Create a temporary table with a list of all id_payments that are on TBTRIGPMMCANC and also TBPROPPAY.

From this list move them from TBPROPPAY to TBPROPPAYH.

Delete them from TBPROPPAY then.

This is my sql i have a problem in the insert statment. I think i need an SQL like before for moving the rows to tbproppayh for every id_payment in the temporary table but i dont know how to write it

The error is :
    E_US0AD8 INSERT: number of target columns must equal the number of target
        list elements in the specified subselect.
        (Thu Jul 18 09:31:23 2013)

```
----Clean up for IN:035466

----Description : Create a temporary table with with a list of all id_payments that are on TBTRIGPMMCANC and also TBPROPPAY.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.set_values AS
SELECT a.id_payment FROM TBTRIGPMMCANC a, TBPROPPAY b
WHERE a.id_payment = b.id_payment 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS WITH NORECOVERY;\p\t\g


--View temporary table

SELECT * FROM session.set_values;\p\t\g
--------------------------------------------------------------

-- Description: Move list from TBPROPPAY to TBPROPPAYH
-------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT id_payment FROM session.set_values
WHERE EXISTS id_payment;\p\t\g

-- Insert into tbproppayh 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Insert into tbproppayh 
Select id_payment FROM TBTRIGPMMCANC a, TBPROPPAY b
WHERE a.id_payment = b.id_payment;\p\t\g
-------------------------------------------------------------

-- Description: DELETE list FROM tbproppay 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Delete FROM tbproppay b WHERE id_payment IN (Select a.id_payment FROM TBTRIGPMMCANC a,  TBPROPPAY b
WHERE a.id_payment = b.id_payment);\p\t\g

-------------------------------------------------------------
--Select from tbproppay & TBTRIGPMMCANC
-------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT a.id_payment FROM TBTRIGPMMCANC a, TBPROPPAY b
WHERE a.id_payment = b.id_payment;\p\t\g    
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a temporary table it might be best to use a view instead.  You can get all the details you need and then take it from the view.

Will post code in a moment.

The error you're getting is fairly self explanatory. You're selecting too many columns for the target.

Answer (score 0):

If table tbproppayh has more than one column you must specify impacted columns on your INSERT statement:

```
Insert into tbproppayh (mycolumn)
Select id_payment
```

Another advice, put alias table before id_payment field otherwise after fix first error, you'll get another error on ambiguos field.

Comment: Insert into tbproppayh (id_payment) Select a.id_payment FROM TBTRIGPMMCANC a, TBPROPPAY b WHERE a.id_payment = b.id_payment. still not working getting a duplicat key on insert error

Comment: where you try to insert value add a condition on existing key in the target table: INSERT INTO...SELECT.... AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'X' FROM tbproppayh where condition on key)